# Count cells which contain a date in a specific month, with a time greater than X, and one further date comparison.

Tags: excel

Ok this is complicated (for me at least!). I'm not a super savvy excel user, and I've managed to get further than I thought without asking for help here, but I'm stuck on the final hurdle.

I'm reporting on a job queue, and want to figure out how many jobs don't get actioned the day they were created. I have a tab called Q which has the list of jobs, when they were created and when they were actioned, along with the name of the job queue they were on.

This list looks like this (I've just x'd out names here): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQ6y.jpg

On a separate tab I'm attempting to summarize this data. I've gotten a few tasks out of the way.

Currently I'm able to count all jobs not actioned on the day they were created with this snippet:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(DAY(Q!$D$7:$D$6655)<>DAY(Q!$H$7:$H$6655)))`

And I can further filter this by job queue using this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(Q!$D$7:$D$6655)<>DAY(Q!$H$7:$H$6655))*((Q!$A$7:$A$6655=E$58)))`

Where the name of the job queue is in E58. And further I've been able to count only those jobs not actioned on the day they were created, by job queue, and by month, with this:

`=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(Q!$D$7:$D$6655)<>DAY(Q!$H$7:$H$6655))*((Q!$A$7:$A$6655=E$58))*(MONTH(Q!$H$7:$H$6655)=B63))`

Where the month is in the B63 cell.

The last step I'm getting stuck on is, I only want to count the jobs not actioned the day they were received, if they we created before some time, say 3pm. We don't expect jobs created late in the day to be completed the same day, right? OK so this is what I've tried and I'm not getting any results:

`=SUMPRODUCT((DAY(Q!$D$7:$D$6655)<>DAY(Q!$H$7:$H$6655))*((Q!$A$7:$A$6655=E$58))*(MONTH(Q!$H$7:$H$6655)=$B63)*(Q!E7:E6655="<"&C59))`

Essentially I'm adding in that last bit `(Q!E7:E6655="<"&C59)`, where C59 has our 'cutoff time'.

This just gives me a zero, which means I've got something wrong, as I can see jobs on that list that satisfy the criteria I'm trying to set.

Comment: If you just do a straight comparison between C59 and one specific time from the list, does it give the expected result?  Check that the data in your "times" column is really just times, and not a date-time formatted to only display the time part.  If you could share a small sample of your actual data that would help.

Comment: Your Column E shows the time value. Does it also contain the information of the day. If you change the format of the cell to Long Date, it might also show the date+time. May be `C59` has the time for a given date and the comparison fails. Also, Why are you writing the formula liek `"<"&C59`

Comment: @TimWilliams yep I've managed to do that. 

I was checking I could actually get a result comparing time values on the same sheet. I've got a test snippet that's just:

`=COUNTIF(E:E,">"&M7)`

Where M7 contains a time like 15:00. This gives me the expected result.

Comment: @nightcrawler23 I'm not really sure, actually, that's just how I thought that needed to be written to compare with a cell. 

Is that incorrect syntax?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I'm not sure how best to share the excel data. 

I just removed formatting from the E column, and it displays values less than 0.99999, which I take to mean they only include the time information, right? Because if there was a date there would be some whole number value, from my cursory reading of (https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/214094).

I've just tried doing more of this in the same sheet, and have found the following snippet also doesn't return the expected value:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(E7:E6655="<"&M7))`

Answer (score 0):

Ah thanks for your help everyone, the issue was that syntax on the time comparison. I'm not sure where I got that from, but changing the last comparison to:

`(Q!E7:E6655<C59)`

Yielded the expected result.

Thanks again.